# How to use self and this combined in a static class?

Tags: php, class, static, this, self

I was wondering how to use the self:: and $this combined in a "static" class?

```
<?php
class Test
{
    static private $inIndex = 0;

    static public function getIndexPlusOne()
    {
        // Can I use $this-> here?
        $this->raiseIndexWithOne();

        return self::inIndex
    }

    private function raiseIndexWithOne()
    {
        // Can I use self:: here?
        self::inIndex++;
    }
}

echo Test::getIndexPlusOne();
```

?>

I added the questions in the code above as well, but can I use self:: in a non-static method and can I use $this-> in a static method to call a non-static function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self` in a non-static method, but you cannot use `$this` in a `static` method.

`self` always refers to the class, which is the same when in a class or object context.
`$this` requires an instance though.

The syntax for accessing static properties is `self::$inIndex` BTW (requires `$`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A static method cannot communicate with methods or properties that require an instance of the class (i.e. non-static properties/methods).

Maybe you're looking for the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: worth to mention: singleton is treated as anti-pattern nowadays.

Comment: I still doubting about the fact if I should use a singleton pattern or a static class for my database class. Singleton looks better, but you can have only 1. With the fact that in the future I will have to migrate my database I would like to have 2 instances and then a static class would be nicer. 

Next to that a static class is faster then a singleton pattern, if I see the benchmarks on the great WWW.

Comment: @pascalvgemert - If you want more than one instance, what are you trying to achieve with static methods and properties? These are "per-class" and not "per-instance".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self::$inIndex` in a non-static method, because you can access static things from non-static methods.

You cannot use `$this->inIndex` in a static method, because a static method is not bound to an instance of the class - therefore $this is not defined in static methods. You can only access methods and properties from a static method if they are static as well.

Answer (score 0):

This would work ( http://codepad.org/99lorvq1 )

```
<?php
class Test
{
    static private $inIndex = 0;

    static public function getIndexPlusOne()
    {
        // Can I use $this-> here?
        self::raiseIndexWithOne();

        return self::$inIndex;
    }

    private function raiseIndexWithOne()
    {
        // Can I use self:: here?
        self::$inIndex++;
    }
}

echo Test::getIndexPlusOne();
```

you can't use $this inside a static method as there is no instance